# Want To Use @Binding Variables In Equations

Tags: binding, initialization, swiftui

```
struct FinanceOutput: View {
@Binding var price: Double
@Binding var down: Double
@Binding var apr: Double  
private var rate: Double = 0.0     
init(price: Binding<Double>, down:Binding<Double>, apr:Binding<Double>, of rate: Double ) {                
  self._price = price
  self._down = down
  self._apr = apr          
 self.rate = rate       
}
```

The above is my code and I do have the @Binding variables defined properly in another view--using @State.

What I'm trying to do is use 'rate' in an equation to define 'apr/12'.  I think I worked it out before in an earlier version of Xcode but now all I get is: "Cannot use instance member 'apr' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available." 
I know I am using Binding types but even when I change type using Double() I still get errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The provided code snapshot compiled correctly at my side. Please show the code the generates mentioned error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to access one of your properties within your struct before init() is complete, e.g.:

```
struct FinanceOutput: View {
    @Binding var price: Double
    @Binding var down: Double
    @Binding var apr: Double

    private var rate: Double = 0.0

    init(price: Binding<Double>, down: Binding<Double>, apr: Binding<Double>, of rate: Double) {
        self._price = price
        self._down = down
        self._apr = apr
        self.rate = rate
    }

    apr = rate // error: Cannot use instance member 'apr' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(apr/rate)")
    }
}
```

You can access the 'rate' property from within the body, e.g.:

```
let input = Input(price: 10.0, down: 10.0, apr: 10.0)

struct FinanceOutput: View {
    @Binding var price: Double
    @Binding var down: Double
    @Binding var apr: Double

    private var rate: Double = 0.0

    init(price: Binding<Double>, down: Binding<Double>, apr: Binding<Double>, of rate: Double) {
        self._price = price
        self._down = down
        self._apr = apr
        self.rate = rate
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(apr/rate)") // shows apr/rate properly
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FinanceOutput(price: input.$price, down: input.$down, apr: input.$apr, of: 12.0)
    }
}

struct Input: View {
    @State var price: Double
    @State var down: Double
    @State var apr: Double

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(price), \(down), \(apr)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked out your answer and I get an undefined answer for (apr/rate)--rate equals 0. I changed "private var rate: Double = 0.0" to "private var rate: Double = 12.0" and still no luck. What I want to do is have a variable where I can calculate a car payment  using my @Binding variables.

Comment: In the example above I used fixed values, and not real-world examples for the numbers. Also, I only divided apr by the rate ( 10.0 / 12.0 = 0.833333 ). If you get a value of 0, maybe you're using a Double to Int conversion with initialization somewhere [like this: Int(apr/rate)]. Try to only use the example above without any modification to understand where and what should you change. Note: the Input class is the one which can be initialized with real numbers, then you can make your equation logic in the FinanceOutput's body (by a method for example).

Comment: Fixed the problem using your answer and another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800369/swiftui-state-variables. Appreciate the information. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad I could help. You can rate my answer, and mark it as solved ;)